# Send a message from Javascript running in a browser to a windows batch file

Tags: javascript, windows, batch-file

Due to an architecture I must work with that likely breaks a lot of very good software design rules, I need to send a message from some javascript code running in a web browser to a windows batch file on the same machine.  The operating systems is Windows Vista or later.  The browsers being used are primarily Chrome and Firefox.  jQuery is also being used with the javascript.

The browser is connected to the internet and their is a server involved, so I could relay the message to the server, and then to the batch file.  Right now I have a batch file that runs every minute or so that could theoretically query the server for any messages.  Other than that, I don't have any good ideas.

Additionally, **this is a "closed" system**.  The client browser, client system, and server are under my complete control.  It is not a situation where the general public is running the Javascript in their browser.  The the client computer can be manipulated to be able to receive the message.

What is a good way to send this message?

Comment: Could you clarify what exactly you want to accomplish. You can send message to server using $.ajax, then can ssh from server to the Windows machine and execute any program on command line. Instead of ssh you can write a simple service that would listen on a socket.

Comment: You could make a firefox addon this does this, but that will take a lot of work.

Comment: Or you can have a local HTTP server (very easy using Bottle.py), and send message using ajax directly to it. No remote server would be involved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## 1. Local HTTP server

From JavaScript, send AJAX request containing your command to local HTTP server. All modern browsers support cross-domain AJAX. The server can pass command as a parameter to the batch file. **Make sure that the server is not accessible from network**.

The advantage of this approach is that you can send response from command back to JavaScript.

- **JavaScript:**

  ```
  $.post('http://localhost:8080', {command: '...'});
  ```
- **Bottle.py server:**

  ```
  #!/usr/bin/python
  from bottle import run, route, request, response
  import subprocess

  @route('/', method='POST')
  def index():
      command = request.POST['command']
      result = subprocess.check_output(['batchfile.bat', command], shell=True)

      response.set_header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
      return result

  run(host='localhost', port=8080, reloader=True)
  ```
- **Or PHP under Apache/nginx:**

  ```
  $result = shell_exec("batchfile.bat " . escapeshellarg($_POST['command']));
  ```
- **Or daemon in PHP**:

  For extra fun it has full shell access and can run commands asynchronously, which allows to launch desktop applications without blocking. It doesn't need Apache.

  Start: `php.exe -f batrunner_daemon.php`

  Use: `$.get('http://localhost:33333/ping -h', function(response) { console.log(response) });`

  ```
  $host = '127.0.0.1';
  $port = 33333;
  $async = false; // enable to run commands without blocking the server (useful for GUI applications)

  $socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
  $open = @socket_bind($socket, $host, $port);
  if ($open) {
      echo "\nListening on http://{$host}:{$port}";
  } else {
      echo "\nError. Port {$port} in use";
      exit;
  }
  socket_listen($socket, 1);

  while(1) {
      $connection = socket_accept($socket);
      $http_request = socket_read($connection, 32768);
      $command = rawurldecode(substr(strstr($http_request, "\r\n", true), 5, -9));

      echo "\nRunning: {$command}...";

      if ($async) {
          $response = pclose(popen('start "" /B ' . $command, 'r')) ? 'error' : 'success';
      } else {
          $response = shell_exec($command);
      }

      echo " Done.";

      socket_write($connection, implode("\r\n", array(
          'HTTP/1.1 200 OK',
          'Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8',
          'Connection: close',
          'Content-Length: ' . strlen($response),
          'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *',
          "\r\n" . $response
      )));
      socket_close($connection);
  }
  ```

  To keep it simple, it doesn't have proper error handling and allows any site to execute anything on your computer, use at your own risk.

  `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` means that any site can receive response from shell. Without this header they obviously still can run commands, but can't receive response.

---

## 2. URI Scheme

I experimented with @mamdrood's idea, and it turned out to be very simple, much easier than HTTP server.

- From HTML, you'll be able to call the batch file like this:

  ```
  <a href="batrunner://somecommand">Wipe all files</a>
  ```
- And here's how the batch file in `C:\mybatfile.bat` can parse commands:

  ```
  @echo off
  SET command=%1
  SET command=%command:batrunner://=%
  echo %command%
  ```

  I'm not very familiar with batch files, and my command name parsing code can be vulnerable. If you know any better please update this answer.
- To associate your batch file with `batrunner://` protocol create `batrunner.reg` and run it once. Substitute `C:\\mybatfile.bat` for your script, path should be escaped.

  ```
  Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

  [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\batrunner]
  "URL Protocol"=""

  [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\batrunner\shell]

  [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\batrunner\shell\open]

  [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\batrunner\shell\open\command]
  @="C:\\mybatfile.bat %1"
  ```

Comment: This sounds pretty good.  Right now I'm using XAMPP.  Is this just as feasable with XAMPP, or do I need to use Bottle?

Comment: You can use XAMPP, sure. On the server, in PHP, you'll have something like shell_exec("batchfile.bat " . escapeshellarg($_POST['command']));

Answer (score 2):

You can also create a little windows application, and use a [URI scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme) to connect the information, just like the BitTorrent magnets or the Skype callto.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, JavaScript running in a browser has no way to communicate with the local file system.  If pages on the web could read and write files on your system it would be very, very bad for everyone. :)

If you need to generate a batch file, you *could* output the file from the server and let the user download it locally and run it, but JavaScript is not going to be of any assistance here.

Comment: Javascript would come into play because the contents of the file on the server would originate from instructions sent by the Javascript

Comment: That's not quite what I meant.  Obviously your interface might use JS for some tasks, but getting a batch file to your desktop will require other methods.

Comment: The batch file is already there because I have control over both the client and server systems.  I apologize though, because I believe I added this clarification after you answered.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you're going to find a "out of the box" way to trigger a local batch file with javascript.  I'm sure the plugin approach will have been advocated by the time I finish posting this, but there's a lot of development overhead attached to that.  Chrome also has some fancy stuff with --enable-local-file-access switches, but there are a lot of caveats attached to that, as well. (just throwing those out there as options to explore).

You might consider just providing a link that downloads the .bat file to the box and executing from there.

**EDIT**
I may have spoken too soon.  If you're using IE, it looks like a js/ActiveX solution can do what you need.  Taken [from here](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1226233).

Comment: He is not particulary using IE, and i'm afraid that Chrome and Firefox make the addons run in a sandbox

Comment: @mamadrood: he may not be particularly using IE, but there is nothing "conventional" about what he's trying to accomplish.  If IE gets the job done in the simplest way possible, I'm willing to bet the OP will use IE ;)

Comment: I totally agree with you, IE may be really helpful in this case.